# ssh keeps spawning swarm of processes even after killing them

Tags: ssh

Our EC2 instance has been experiencing very slow connection lately.
After we investigate deeper, we found out that there are few hundred ssh processes running, and they are all trying to connect to the same host (i.e it's almost like ddos attack against that host).

```
ps aux | grep ssh
root       971  0.0  0.0  61364  3084 ?      Ss Dec11   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      7649  0.0  0.0 105628  4228 ?      Ss 03:57   0:00 sshd: ubuntu [priv] 
ubuntu    7811  0.0  0.0 106404  2740 ?      S  03:57   0:00 sshd: ubuntu@pts/0  
ubuntu    8616  0.0  0.0  44012  2516 pts/2  S  04:02   0:00 ssh deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ubuntu    8618  0.0  0.0  44012  2512 pts/2  S  04:02   0:00 ssh deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ubuntu    8620  0.0  0.0  44012  2512 pts/2  S  04:02   0:00 ssh deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ubuntu    8622  0.0  0.0  44012  2512 pts/2  S  04:02   0:00 ssh deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ubuntu    8624  0.0  0.0  44012  2516 pts/2  S  04:02   0:00 ssh deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
...
```

Here I logged in as ubuntu. I vaguely remember I executed the command a while ago trying to connect to the host, but ssh outputs many instances of itself and the terminal got frozen, and since then we have been experiencing the slow connection issue.

Anyhow, I tried to kill all of the ssh processes, but they just keep coming back and eventually slow down the whole system connection again.

```
$ killall -9 ssh
```

Any idea what went wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: have a look who started them. You should get the idea by adding `f` option to `ps` command.